# Want to add request Headers to an iframe src request using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I would like to open my external application using iframe. I have tried below code but it did not work for me.

I am calling external application inside my internal solution.

I did some research but could not find proper solution. `BUrl` contains external application Url.

Please show me a way to do this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Tried so many approach but nothing worked for me.

```
@{   
    string BUrl = ViewBag.BUrl;
    string Token = ViewBag.Token;       
}   
<div id="myiframe" src="about:blank" style="position: fixed; z-index: 999; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; left:0; filter: alpha(opacity=60); opacity: 0.6; -moz-opacity: 0.8;display:none"></div>

#Approach1

 $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@BUrl'.replace(/amp;/g, ''),
                type: 'GET',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + '@Token');
                },
                success: function (data) {                 
                $("#myiframe").attr('src', "/")
                $("#myiframe").contents().find('html').html(data);                   
            },
                statusCode: {
                    400: function () {
                        alert("server returned a bad request response.");
                    }
                }                
            });
        });

#Approach2

 $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@BUrl'.replace(/amp;/g, ''),
                type: 'GET',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + '@Token');
                },
                success: function (data) {
              $("#myiframe").attr('src', "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(data))                                 
            },
                statusCode: {
                    400: function () {
                        alert("server returned a bad request response.");
                    }
                }                
            });
        });

#Approach3

           $.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: "https://yourdomain.com/gethtml",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
         xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + '@Token');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var iframeDoc = document.querySelector('#myiframe').contentWindow.document;
        iframeDoc.open('text/html', 'replace');
        iframeDoc.write(data);
        iframeDoc.close();
    }
});

#Approach 4

           $.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: "https://yourdomain.com/gethtml",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
         xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + '@Token');
    },
    success: function(data) {
         var iframe = document.getElementById('myiframe');
        iframe.contentWindow.contents = data;
        iframe.src = 'javascript:window["contents"]';
    }
});
```

Comment: seems overly complicated.  Why not handle the call in a controller... so set the src to your own page, and process the external request in your controller.  Return the necessary view/html from your controller.  For purely JS method you might need to include a sample of what "data" is returned here.  You could just set the src to a simple page to make things easier to append.  (ex: blank_html_page.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I try to add a filter to check the header, and in my side, it works well. Hope it will useful to you.

**My test code:**

```
<iframe id="myiframe" style="position: fixed; z-index: 999; border-color:yellow; height: 50%; width: 50%; top: 20%; left:20%;filter: alpha(opacity=60); opacity: 0.6; -moz-opacity: 0.8;display:none"></iframe>
<button id="TestButton" onclick="functionToExecute()">click</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function functionToExecute()
    {
        var url="https://localhost:44374/Home/Privacy";
        $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('MyHeader', "SUCCESS");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#myiframe").css("display","block")
                    $("#myiframe").attr("src",url)
                },
               error:function (error)
                {
                    console.log(error);
                },
                statusCode: {
                    400: function () {
                        alert("server returned a bad request response.");
                    }
                }                
            });
    }
</script>
```

**My filter for head**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;



namespace MyTest.Filter
{
public class ResponseHeaderAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
private StringValues MyHeader;



public ResponseHeaderAttribute()
{ }



public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
{
context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("MyHeader", out MyHeader);
if (MyHeader != StringValues.Empty)
{
context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("success", "success");
base.OnResultExecuting(context);
}
else
{
context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("AA", "BB");
}
}
}
}
```

**Privacy View, like your Authorization**

```
[ResponseHeader()]
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
return View();
}
```

**Test Result:**

[image]